# Using dynamicHelpers in routes setup with Express and node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I began using node.js+express combo very recently and I stumbled at a need to use dynamicHelpers not only in my views but also inside my routes setup (routes/index.js in default express config). Should I use some different pattern?

app.js

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
    translate : function(req, res) {
        return translate;
    },
    language : function(req, res) {
        return req.session.language || "en";
    },
});
```

Below I would like to have a convenient access to whatever I set for my dynamicHelpers because in my mind it is the same context .. so why set it up two times?

```
var routes = {};
routes.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title : 'My webpage',
        categories : categoryPositions,
        referrer : req.header("Referrer"),
        languages : ["pl", "en", "de"],
        <----- here I would like to use my dynamicHelpers (for example translate)
    })
};
```

I know I can pass my data in many ways but I do not want to repeat my code
and want to set up the common context only once and as cleanly as polssible. I welcome any criticism and good advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So actually the solution is to use not yet released express 3.0, modify:

`npm install -g express@3.0`

Follow https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x , http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/

The new express simplified dynamicHelpers to the use of `res.locals` which are both available in the routes setup and then bound to the view.

Example:

```
// app.
app.locals.use(function(req, res) {
    var language = req.session.language || "en";
    res.locals.language = language;
    res.locals.translate = function(clause) {
        return translate(clause, language);
    };
});
```

In the routes setup I can now access both `res.locals.language` and `res.locals.translate`.
In my views I simply can use `translate('something')`.

Comment: it seems that 3.0rc don't support app.locals.use , instead, use app.use(fn) before app.use(app.router);

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But what if I have a callback in `translate`, say it's requesting some resource. Then how would it return the result.

Answer (score 3):

functions.js

```
module.exports = {
  translate : function(req, res) {
    return translate;
  },
  language : function(req, res) {
    return req.session.language || "en";
  },
};
```

helpers.js

```
var functions = require('./functions');

app.dynamicHelpers({
  translate : functions.translate,
  language : functions.language
});
```

Depending on what you need you can also write the helpers like this

```
var functions = require('./functions');

app.dynamicHelpers( functions );
```

routes.js

```
var functions = require('./functions');

var routes = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
      title : 'My webpage',
      categories : categoryPositions,
      referrer : req.header("Referrer"),
      languages : ["pl", "en", "de"],
      stuff: functions.translate(req, res) // <----- here I would like to use my dynamicHelpers (for example translate)
    })
  }
};
```

Comment: I think your suggestion is almost all right, thanks for the effort! However, please consider that `functions.translate(req, res)` is gonna be called twice. First manually setting up `stuff:` and second by the Express itself for the particular view. I would like to know whether it is possible to not repeat the setting up and have it happen only once. If it cannot be improved in a neat way then I will accept your solution.

Comment: I am afraid I don't fully understand what you mean then. I thought you just needed to use your helper function in your route. If you already have it in your view and that's what you want why are you setting it up in your route again?

Comment: For each request, each element in your `functions` is called and a value is set in particular view context - this is done automatically. When you do `stuff: functions.translate(req, res)` it means that `functions.translate(req, res)` is gonna be called twice. First, manually in stuff's initialization, and second by Express. Best solution would be not to call dynamicHelpers twice per each request and response. What if the helpers initialization would be somehow more complex - like reading a file perhaps? I hope I explained my point a bit better.

Comment: I think I have found a solution and posted my own answer. I upvoted yours for a good try. ;)